# Add to multidemensional array given only a value and sub keys for location

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

```
Array
(    [Fixed Assets] => Array
    (
        [0] => 150
        [1] => Array
            (
                [Equimpent] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Office Computer
                        [1] => Office Printer
                    )
            )
        [2] => Array
            (
                [Furniture and Fixtures] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Desk
                        [1] => Desk Chair
                    )
            )
    )
)
```

Employed as a heirarchial account naming and numbering schema, Account Numbers can be derived from the above sample array as follows...

- **Fixed Assets** (*Parent Account*) #**150**
- **Equimpent** (*Child of Fixed Assets*) #**150-1**
- **Furniture and Fixtures** (*Child of Fixed Assets*) #**150-2**
- **Desk Chair** (*Child of Furniture and Fixtures*) #**150-2-1**

My puzzle is how to code the addition of New Accounts to the array given 
only the desired New Account Name,and the derived account number of its 
target parent account.

For example...

```php
<?php  
//Chart of Accounts
$coa = array('Fixed Asset'=>array(150,array('Equimpent'=>array('computer','printer')),array('Furniture and Fixtures'=>array('desk','chair'))));
//global $coa;
$new_account ="Office File Cabinet";//from ajax post
$target_base_no ="150-2";//from ajax post
//won't know if or how many subkeys will may be included 
//but would result in something like...

$coa['unknown_parent_of_acct_no_150'][2][] = $new_account;
?>
```

I'm totally blocked...
Reciprocally I suppose I might ask...
How might I determine the account name for account# 150-2 ?
Here is the COA array in context.

```
Array
(
[Cash Bank] => Array
    (
        [0] => 100
        [1] => Checking
        [2] => Paypal
        [3] => Petty Cash
        [4] => Savings
        [5] => Deposits Pending
    )

[Accounts Receivable] => Array
    (
        [0] => 110
        [1] => AR-AlternaMart
    )

[Inventory] => Array
    (
        [0] => 120
    )

[Other Current Assets] => Array
    (
        [0] => 130
        [1] => Pre-Paid Hosting
    )

[Fixed Assets] => Array
    (
        [0] => 150
        [1] => Array
            (
                [Equipment] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Computer
                        [1] => Printer
                    )

            )

        [2] => Array
            (
                [Furniture And Fixtures] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => Desk
                        [1] => Desk Chair
                    )

            )

    )

[Accumulated Depreciation] => Array
    (
        [0] => 160
        [1] => AD-Computer
        [2] => AD-Printer
        [3] => AD-Desk
        [4] => AD-Desk Chair
    )

[Accounts Payable] => Array
    (
        [0] => 200
        [1] => AP-Unearned Shipping
    )

[Credit Cards Payable] => Array
    (
        [0] => 210
        [1] => Wells Fargo Visa
    )

[Sales Tax Payable] => Array
    (
        [0] => 220
        [1] => CO
        [2] => 80227
        [3] => 80214
        [4] => IL
    )

[Accrued Payroll Taxes] => Array
    (
        [0] => 230
    )

[Other Current Liabilities] => Array
    (
        [0] => 240
    )

[Loans Payable] => Array
    (
        [0] => 270
    )

[Notes Payable] => Array
    (
        [0] => 280
    )

[Capital] => Array
    (
        [0] => 300
    )

[Drawing] => Array
    (
        [0] => 320
    )

[Sales] => Array
    (
        [0] => 400
    )

[Other Income] => Array
    (
        [0] => 401
        [1] => Shipping
    )

[Commissions] => Array
    (
        [0] => 402
        [1] => AlternaMart Commissions
    )

[Sales Discounts] => Array
    (
        [0] => 450
    )

[Sales Returns and Allowances] => Array
    (
        [0] => 451
    )

[Shipping Discounts] => Array
    (
        [0] => 452
    )

[Reimbursed Shipping] => Array
    (
        [0] => 453
    )

[Cost of Goods Sold] => Array
    (
        [0] => 500
        [1] => COGS Shipping
    )

[Expense] => Array
    (
        [0] => 600
        [1] => BSC Checking
        [2] => Paypal Transaction Fees
        [3] => Alternamart Transaction Fees
        [4] => Commissions Expense
        [5] => Interest Expense
        [6] => Internet Service
        [7] => Web Hosting
        [8] => Rent Expense
        [9] => Telephone
        [10] => Utilities
        [11] => Postage
        [12] => Office Supplies
        [13] => Miscellaneous Supplies
        [14] => Advertising
        [15] => Salaries And Wages
        [16] => Payroll Taxes
        [17] => Dues And Subscriptions
        [18] => Miscellaneous Expenses
        [19] => Legal And Accounting
        [20] => Insurance
        [21] => Vehicles Expense
        [22] => Depreciation Expense
        [23] => Travel And Entertainment
        [24] => Bad Debt Expense
        [25] => Ask Accountant
    )

[Ask Accountant] => Array
    (
        [0] => 900
    )
```

)

Comment: So the *account name* is equipment or furniture?

Comment: @cillosis the target sub-account is "Furniture and Fixtures" but all I know is the target account number (150-2) in my example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I get it right:...

Split `$target_base_no` by - `$arr = explode('-', $target_base_no)`
Search your `$coa` array for value = 150 ($arr[0]), sth like that:

```
    foreach($coa as $row) {
       if ($arr[0] == $row[.....]
    }
```

Use the second splited value ($arr[1]) to identify where to insert.

Edited: You should create a reversed indexed array for a direct access to the right value. We are saving the nummeric values as keys and the text values as value (which can be used as index for the `$coa` array:

```
$index = array();
foreach($coa as $key => $value) {
     $index[$value[0]] = $key;
}
```

Afterwards you just access your data `$coa[$index[$arr[0]]]` (you should check if the field exists)

Comment: Thanks, but I don't guess I see it.
At a minimum wo0uld require $key = array_search_recursive($arr[0],$coa); but I have yet to find a viable array_search_recursive function, and not sure I'm up to rolling my own. Also, not clear on your meaning "use a hash for direct index on the field". Care to elaborate?

Comment: This means to use an index for the parent ArrayElement, like:
$index[150] = &$parent_index[x];
Can you please post an example for more data? sth. how it would look if you had data for 150 and 151

Comment: "how it would look if you had data for 150 and 151"
Maybe better to post the total array for context (there would not be 150 and 151)  In accounting parlance, 100 accounts are commonly asset accounts, 200 accounts are liabilites,  300 accounts are capitol or equity accounts, 400 accounts are revenue accounts, 500 accounts for Cost of Goods Sold, and 600 accounts for Expenses.
See Array in Context in updated OP

Comment: Nice! I see it. Clean and simple. Thank you!